# How can I access Glassfish v2 Admin Console from Apache httpd?

Tags: glassfish, apache, mod-jk

We have a Glassfish running behind an Apache Webserver. Direct requests to the application server are blocked by the firewall. So we have the webserver forwarding requests to the app server via mod_jk. This all works fine for the web apps deployed on x80 ports of Glassfish. But am now left wondering, how do I access the Admin Console GUI? I can do most of the Admin Console things using asadmin, but it'd be good to have the GUI as well.

Thanks!
Nirav

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a new VirtualHost or an Alias which will map to the Glassfish admin console?